# convert decimal to Ascii, but i have decimal in defferent format?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

@Verdolino helps me to convert string from Ascii to decimal and do some operation to each Char and collect them in textbox.
this is the code:

```
 Dim sText As String
    sText = TextBox6.Text
    sASC = sText.Select(Function(t) (BigInteger.Pow(Asc(t), ee) Mod n).ToString()).Aggregate(Function(t1, t2) t1 & "," & t2)
    TextBox7.Text = sASC
```

I want the input like this: 
`Input: 912,697,583,1065,261 
operation = 912^3 mod 1073,697^3 mod 1073,583^3 mod 1073,1065^3 mod 1073,261^3 mod 1073 
output: Ascii code of each group of numbers between comma.`

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am beginner, i tried to convert all numbers to Ascii but 
by this code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: please edit your post and paste that code there

Comment: you changed your question, those numbers do not represent valid ascii numbers, so I'm getting confused what are you asking

Comment: Sorry, Imagine that you want to input this in textbox1.text:
912,697,583,1065,261

And do op like this:
912^3 mod 7 ,697^3 mod 7 ,583^3 mod 7 ,1065^3 mod 7 ,261^3 mod 7 


and then the output will be like this:
qussai


 suppose that "912^3 mod 7" equal "q" in Ascii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Upadated**:

```
Dim rr As String = TextBox10.Text
textbox11.text = ""
Dim numbers As String() = rr.Split(","C)
    For Each number As String In numbers
        Dim tempNumb as BigInteger =  ((BigInteger.Parse(number))^3) mod 1073
        Try
            Dim asciiChar As Char = Chr(tempNumb)
        Finally
            textbox11.text = textbox11.text + " There is no ascii code for: " + tempNumb
        End Try
        textbox11.text = textbox11.text + tempNumb
    Next
```

With hex:

```
Dim rr As String = TextBox10.Text
    textbox11.text = ""
    Dim numbers As String() = rr.Split(","C)
        For Each number As String In numbers
            Dim tempNumb as BigInteger =  ((BigInteger.Parse(number))^3) mod 1073
            Try
                Dim hexNumber as Integer = Hex(tempNumb)
                Dim intFromHex as Integer = Convert.ToInt32(hexNumber, 16)
                Dim asciiChar As Char = Chr(tempNumb)
            Finally
                textbox11.text = textbox11.text + " There is no ascii code for: " + tempNumb
            End Try
            textbox11.text = textbox11.text + tempNumb
        Next
```

Comment: this code deosn't work, maybe i didn't use correctly. could you check it again. plz.

Comment: try now, if you want to do more then just store in a list

Comment: I changed it one more time.

Comment: you didn't use inputbox "rr" and i need output in textbox11.text

Comment: all fixed, anything else you have problems with

Comment: What is this Error mean?
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Comment: that error refer to this line:

Dim tempNumb as Integer =  (Convert.toInt32(number)^3) mod 1073

Comment: it was missing brackets, fixed

Comment: what about if i want "tempNumb" is Biginteger type??

Comment: you can make even decimal

Comment: i still don't get how you intend to get accurate ascii codes.

Comment: Surry, but i couldn't do it. I am still have problem.

Comment: try now and as of 912^3 mod 7 = "q", thats not true, mod number of that is 1 which is space. 912^3 mod 1073 this gives nonexistent ascii code of 600 and something.  Yoy main problem is "^3 mod 1073" and logic behind it

Comment: let me show you what i want:
first group of the input is "912"==>
==> (912^815 mode 1073 = 109) ==> convert "109" to Ascii ==> m

Comment: then change ^3 to ^815

Comment: each time you write something different, you know

Comment: Sorry about that, maybe i couldn't describe my problem clearly.

Comment: 912^815 is biginteger, how to rewrite this code with biginteger type.

Comment: this is screenshot of my issue:

(http://s12.postimg.org/r2t2lwz6l/Ashampoo_Snap_2016_03_25_16h42m24s_002.png)

Comment: fix this to what you want, "^3) mod 1073"

Comment: because it doesn't add zero on the left,

EX:

97 must be 079 to convert it to Ascii.
and 
Space 32 must be 032 to convet it to Space in Ascii

Comment: Can i add zero "0" on the left of each group to convert it to Ascii.

Comment: does this doesn't work for you Dim asciiChar As Char = Chr(tempNumb)? Whats the number of tempNumb

Comment: OMG, really you are my hero ^_^

Comment: still one thing. how to convert this to hex and convert it back.
912,697,583,1065,261,627,53,703,544,697,924,1003,697.

Comment: You can use hex(value)

Comment: could you Update your code with (convert to hex and opposite).? plz

Comment: sure, tell me more about when you whant it to change to hex and when convert it back

Comment: in same code, how to convert this to Hex and convert it back to Decimal!

912,697,583,1065,261,627,53,703,544,697,924,1003,697